# How to mock HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse using Mockito

Tags: mockito

I am trying to mock the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects in order to set parameters and attributes to the request.

I don't have the package `MockHttpServletRequest`. Is there any way I can get the mock object of `HttpServletRequest` without using `MockHttpServletRequest`?

Comment: It seems that you are struggling with mocking ... as said: you better read some tutorials, like: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Comment: Simply worked with Spring's mock package.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use mockito to mock HttpServletRequest  and HttpServletResponse

```
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
```

Comment: This is throwing error -
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
 at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the same code as want2learn, but still facing errors. Long story short **dependency** issue. I was using runner which was dependent on Mockito2 and mocking with the help of Mockito1 or just Mockito causing it to fail. (I am still learning JUnit so I don't know how it works yet). Also, I am doing everything without Spring. If anyone needs example code comment below.